# Power-Troubleshooter Event 1 No Longer Logged

Tags: windows-7, standby

Power-Troubleshooter Event 1 No Longer Logged

Since last week, when the computer resumes from S3 standby, Power-Troubleshooter Event 1 no longer gets logged in Event viewer -> System

Why is this?  How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the missing log is Apple iTunes and related software.

The event logging resumed after I uninstalled:

- iTunes. Product Version: 12.4.1.6.
- Apple Mobile Device Support. Product Version: 9.3.0.15.
- Apple Software Update. Product Version: 2.2.0.150.
- Apple Application Support (64-bit) --

Comment: I don’t get the logs either, but I don’t have iTunes, so it’s not that.